# Uncaught Errror: Class FPDI_Protection not found despite of its presence in the FPDI_Protection.php file

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I am trying to password protect PDF documents with a PHP script. So I downloaded and included the FPDI_Protection.php file in my script which contains the FPDI_Protection class.

But when I'm trying to execute the script it says the Class FPDI_Protection not found when its clearly present in the mentioned file. I also checked other answers on stackoverflow which says to use setasign\ but no such namespace is declared in file containing the class.

Also I'm not using composer for dependencies.

My Code goes like

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); 


function pdfEncrypt ($origFile, $password, $destFile){
 require_once("assets/fpdi/FPDI_Protection.php");

 $pdf =& new FPDI_Protection();
 // set the format of the destinaton file
 $pdf->FPDF("P", "in", array('8.27','11.69'));
 //calculate the number of pages from the original document
 $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($origFile);

 // copy all pages from the old unprotected pdf in the new one
 for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
      $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
      $pdf->addPage();
      $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
 }


 //password for the pdf file
 $password = "test";

 //name of the original file
 $origFile = "cv.pdf";

 //name of the destination file 
 $destFile ="cv_test.pdf";

 //encrypt the book and create the protected file
 pdfEncrypt($origFile, $password, $destFile );

?>
```

I have my FPDI_Protection.php file under assets folder of current directory of the script.
And I have downloaded the script from [here](http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/fpdi.zip).

In case that link doesn't work see the whole article [here](http://www.idsecuritysuite.com/blog/password-protect-a-pdf-document-in-php).

Tried all possible way to fix but none of them work. Can you please point out the mistake I am doing ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a script from a blog post which is nearly 14 years old! Just use the official and up to date version of the FPDI Protection class which is available [here](https://github.com/Setasign/fpdi-protection).